# Remote restart else do nothing - powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to restart a list of computers from a text file. To test if the computer is up first. This seems simple, but just can't get it to work.

I can't see where I'm going wrong

```
$comp = Get-Content C:\temp\srv.txt
$s = Get-Credential 
foreach ($comps in $comp) 
{
    {
if(-not(Test-Connection -ComputerName $comp -Count 1 ))
   {
   Write-Host "$comp unavailable"
    }
}
 else 
 {
Restart-Computer -ComputerName $comp -force -Credential $s

    }
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, you just had a couple extra brackets in the code which were not needed.

```
$comp = Get-Content C:\temp\srv.txt
$s = Get-Credential 
foreach ($comps in $comp) 
{    
    if(-not(Test-Connection -ComputerName $comp -Count 1 ))
    {
        Write-Host "$comp unavailable"
    }
    else 
    {
        Restart-Computer -ComputerName $comp -force -Credential $s
    }
}
```